# IS Obfs4 blocked in China now?

Tags: obfs4

[image]

My private Obsf4 bridge is 
"obfs4 205.185.117.208:38571  4C1B1F2F9FF164243E18C571C3920493BA884C64  cert=DXGNrwW4IwFG4zUMzk7GIwP35OTH7iNQ8ZirOublem8eulgLB7vsHQD2V2E0bn2woTdsLQ iat-mode=0"
When I tried connect Tor by my private bridge, TBB just showed me "Loading network status",I waited and waited but nothing changed.

Meanwhile, less and less Plugintransports. What the hell is going on Tor? We need more kinds of PT and I have donated twice. Any reasons? Please

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried meek azure? My new obfs4 bridge gets users from china for few weeks then traffic stops, censors learns too.

Comment: Meek-azure work normally without any problem. Obfs4 may be disturbed